# jupyter notebook not launching from the anaconda command prompt

Tags: jupyter

(base) C:\Users\kpl16587.KPLC>d:

(base) D:>jupyter notebook

[I 13:47:49.286 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 13:47:49.289 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 13:47:49.291 NotebookApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.

I reinstalled Jupyter since i could not launch and now i get the above error.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, by modifying C:\Users\username.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py

line---#c.NotebookApp.browser = ''

to

---#c.NotebookApp.browser =u'C:/Home/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

Now Jupyter notebook launching perfectly.